# Check_box_tag input id

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, collections

I have a check_box_tag that looks like this :

```
check_box_tag('shipping_method[shipping_categories][]', category.id, 
@shipping_method.shipping_categories.include?(category))
```

When inspecting the output in browser, I have the following :

```
<input id="shipping_method_shipping_categories_" 
name="shipping_method[shipping_categories][]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

I don't get why the id has no "id", meaning that the underscore at the end of

```
id="shipping_method_shipping_categories_"
```

makes me expect an id for this particular shipping_category.

Any of you guys and gals have thoughts on this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't get why the id has no "id", meaning that the underscore at the
>   end of id="shipping_method_shipping_categories_" makes me expect an id
>   for this particular shipping_category.

That is the default behavior of the [*`check_box_tag`*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag). In other words it is constructed that way. When you look upon the code of how it is constructed, you will see the below

```
# File actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb, line 374
def check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
  html_options = { "type" => "checkbox", "name" => name, "id" => sanitize_to_id(name), "value" => value }.update(options.stringify_keys)
  html_options["checked"] = "checked" if checked
  tag :input, html_options
end
```

So, the `"id"` is constructed with the method `sanitize_to_id(name)`. So I've further looked upon `sanitize_to_id(name)` to see its code and I've found this

```
def sanitize_to_id(name)
  name.to_s.delete("]").tr("^-a-zA-Z0-9:.", "_")
end
```

So, `shipping_method[shipping_categories][].to_s.delete("]").tr("^-a-zA-Z0-9:.", "_")` returns `shipping_method_shipping_categories_`. That explains its behavior.

If you want to achieve what you are expecting, I recommend you to go with [*`collection_check_boxes`*](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)

For example,

```
collection_check_boxes(:post, :author_ids, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial)
```

returns

```
<input id="post_author_ids_1" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />
```